# Using a field inside the same record in a SOQL's WHERE clause

Tags: soql, lookup

Let's say I have my `Account` object containing a custom `Asset__c` lookup field. I'm looking for a way to make an SOQL request similar to this one:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    AccountId,
    Account.Asset__r.Id
FROM
    Asset
WHERE
    Account.Asset__r.Id = Id
```

So, is it possible to re-use inside the same SOQL one of the field of a record?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, but you can create the same effect with the use of a formula field that performs the calculation and then use that in your where clause.

**Formula Field**

```
IF(Id = Account.Asset__r.Id, 'Yes', 'No')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT id FROM Asset where MyFormulaField__c = 'Yes'
```

**When to Use**

Depending on your use case looping can work just fine, especially for smaller tables.  For larger tables, i.e. 50K+ records, you'd need a batch class to continue using the looping mechanism.  In these cases it may be quicker to just create the formula field, in particular if it's part of a data cleanup or analysis project.  Once you're done using it just delete the field.

Comment: Didn't thought of that, but that's a great idea. I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

After finding this page in the Salesforce.com documentation:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm#fieldexpression

> You must supply a native value—other field names or calculations are not permitted.

I guess it is not possible, I will need to process the records using a loop. If anyone has another solution to embed this inside the `SOQL`, feel free to reply to this :)!